# Using Ubuntu "Connect to Server" to mount Windows share?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, mount, network-shares

I have a system with Ubuntu 9.10 installed.

I can connect to remote windows shares by using the "connect to server" under "places" menu.

I can't figure out where these mount in the file system. Is it possible to mount it in the file system.

And I can't install smbfs or anything else. I need to use only what comes on the live CD, as there is no internet connection and no way to get in packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu's Gnome desktop uses GVFS to mount those shares.

You should be able to use the following command to mount your shares.  If you have a persistent home directory, you can add this or similar to some startup files.

```
gvfs-mount smb://server-name/share-name
```

The mount should be available under your home directory, in *`/home/username/.gvfs`*.  For example, on my system I did the following:

```
$ gvfs-mount smb://my-home-server/my-share
$ ls -F ~/.gvfs
my-share on my-home-server/
```

So that share is directly accessible (on commandline and in the desktop environment) via the mountpoint *`/home/username/.gvfs/my-share on my-home-server`*.

According to several sources, if you are using this over SSH or another situation where you aren't running the full Gnome setup, you may need to use *dbus-launch* to mount the share:

```
dbus-launch gvfs-mount smb://server-name/share-name
```

([source1](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2008/12/08/access-gvfs-mounts-from-the-command-line/), [source2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1390955))

Comment: if you want it mounted somewhere else, i believe this is possible, but you may have to modify a config file somewhere.  alternately you can create a symlink to *~/.gvfs* for easy access.

Comment: I want to confirm that you need dbus-launch over ssh. Also the complete syntax for the Windows share should look like this: `smb://DOMAIN\;username@server-name/share-name`